# Profile permission locked in Prestashop 1.7

Tags: prestashop-1.7

I am working with Prestashop 1.7.1.2. I want to modify profile permissions but they are locked (I am superAdmin)

[image]

[image]

How can I unlock it?

Answer (score 1):

This a currently known bug in Prestashop. Restore you database table called 'ps_access' and you should be fine.